# Higher derivatives of multilinear map

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, banach-spaces, multilinear-algebra

Let, $E,F$ are two banach spaces and $V$ be an open subset of $E.$ $f_1,f_2:V\to F$ be twice continuously differentiable function.Let, $H$ be a multilinear map from $F\times F$ to a banach space $G$ and $\phi:U\to G$ defined as $\phi(x)= H(f_1(x),f_2(x)).$Now ,compute $D^2 \phi.$

I can compute $D^1(\phi)$ and that is,
$D^1\phi(x)(z)=
H(Df_1(x)(z),f_2(x))+H(f_1(x),Df_2(x)(z))\text{
 where}~z\in E.$

Now, to compute the second derivative I am facing problem. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you continue applying the same rule to each term,

> $D^1\phi(x)(z)= H(Df_1(x)(z),f_2(x))+H(f_1(x),Df_2(x)(z))$

$D^2\phi(x)(z,w)=\\= H(D^2f_1(x)(z,w),f_2(x)) + H(Df_1(x)(z),Df_2(x)(w))\\ + H(Df_1(x)(w),Df_2(x)(z)) + H(f_1(x),D^2f_2(x)(z,w))$

Comment: Shouldn't it be, $D^2\phi(x)(z,w)=\\= H(D^2f_1(x)(w,z),f_2(x)) + H(Df_1(x)(z),Df_2(x)(w))\\ + H(Df_1(x)(w),Df_2(x)(z)) + H(f_1(x),D^2f_2(x)(w,z)) ?$

Comment: No, why? Those auxiliary arguments do come in that order. Let $g(x)=Df_1(x)(z)$, then $Dg(x)(w)=D^2f_1(x)(z)(w)=D^2f_1(x)(z,w)$

Comment: We define, $\phi: BL(E,F)\to F$ by $\phi(T)=T(z).$ Then, $g(x)=\phi(Df_1(x))$ ,so by chain rule, $g'(x)(w)=\phi'(Df_1(x))(D^2f_1(x))(w)=(D^2f_1(x)(w))(z)=D^2f_1(x)(w,z)$

Comment: Differentiating my $g(x)=Df_1(x)(z)$ with respect to $x$ (ignoring the free variable $z$ in that expression, treating it like a fixed parameter) we get another linear map with respect to a new auxiliary variable $w$, the outermost variable (compared to the "innermost" variable $z$ which had been plugged there first), that's why I put it into the 2nd slot of the resulting bilinear map $D^2f_1(x)$. But, it's the matter of your convention, as long as you keep track which slot each argument goes to in the final expression. E.g., 2nd derivative of $x^2$ is the "either" of $B(z,w)=zw+wz=B'(w,z)$.